# jquery get the input element in different parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html

```
 <div>                                
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="search_input form-control" placeholder="Search..."></div>
      <span>
         <img src="images/btn-reset-search.png" class="clear_text" alt="">
       </span>
 </div>
```

I want to get the input field when I click on the image having classname:  `clear_text`.

I tried :

```
 $('.clear_text').parent().prev('input');
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Within the click handler, it becomes `$(this).parent().prev('input');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.clear_text').on("click", function()
{
    $(this).closest("div").find("input");
});
```

It navigates to the first parent `div`(`closest("div")`) then searches for an `input`(`find("input")`) inside it. You can use `input:first` if you not sure how many inputs the `div` element may have.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clear_text', function(){
     var $input = $(this).closest("div").find("input");
     //do whatever you want with $input, $input.val(), $input.addClass(), etc..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('.clear_text').parent().prev().find('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
$(function(){
  $(".clear_text").click(function(){
    var inputField = $(this).parent().closest('input[type="text"]');
  })
})
```

**OR**

```
$(function(){
  $(".clear_text").click(function(){
    var inputField = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]');
  })
})
```

Here `inputField` is the required input.

Comment: I don't think this will work! You might need to refer [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: May i know the reason.

Comment: Reson: Updated in first comment look closely at link